# A proof that Mobius transformation preserve symmetry.

Tags: complex-analysis

By definition, the points $z$ and $z^{\ast}$ are said to be **symmetric with respect to the circle $C$** through $z_1,z_2,z_3$ if and only if $(z^{\ast},z_1,z_2,z_3)=\overline{(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)}$, where $(w,z_1,z_2,z_3)$ denotes the cross ratio.

Suppose that $z,z^{\ast}$ are symmetric with respect to the circle $C_1$ and $T(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ is a Mobius transformation which carries the circle $C_1$ into a circle $C_2$. I want to prove that $T(z),T(z^{\ast})$ are symmetric with respect to the circle $C_2$.

**Here is my proof**:
Let $z_1,z_2,z_3\in C_1$ distinct. Hence $T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3)\in C_2$ distinct.
Since cross ratio is invariant under Mobius transformation, it follows that
$$
\begin{split}
(T(z^{\ast}),T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3))
&=(z^{\ast},z_1,z_2,z_3)\\
&=\overline{(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)}\\
&=\overline{(T(z),T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3))}\quad QED
\end{split}
$$
Does this proof is correct? Thanks.

Comment: That is correct. Preservation of symmetry (wrt to circles/lines) is an immediate consequence  of the preservation of the cross ratio.

Comment: Thanks Martin. My question arose since I saw in Ahlfors' book "Complex analysis" a different proof (p. 28, Section 3.3 in the first edition): First he prove the assertion under the assumption that $C_1=\Bbb R$ and than handle the general case (using some intermediate transformation). It was very unclear why to go that way...

Comment: I own that book but do not have it with me right now :) It may be a matter of in which order things are proved.